# How to link bootstrap buttons with input checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to find a way on how to link bootstrap button classes in the following manner?

```
 <!-- HTML -->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">
                    <i class="flaticon-groceries"></i>
                    <span>Grocery</span>
                    <a>select</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">
                    <i class="flaticon-cooking"></i>
                    <span>Cooking</span>
                    <a>select</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <label class="">
                <input type="checkbox">
                    <i class="flaticon-house-cleaning"></i>
                    <span>Cleaning</span>
                    <a>select</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6>
            <label class="">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySelfHandyman" >
                    <i class="flaticon-handyman-1"></i>
                    <span>Handyman</span>
                    <a>select</a>
            </label>
        </div>


 <!-- jquery -->
$('input[type="checkbox"]).on('change',function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

using input as radio type is not an option. they have to be checkbox. Results that are desired is that when checkbox = true, button (label in this case) should be active and when we select a different checkbox previous button should got to its default state and the current one should be active. Situation also call for only 1 checkbox to be selected at one time. jquery is in place to solve that problem, but I am unable to toggle the buttons between default and active states on checkbox clicks. Currently I have to click on the buttons twice to remove the active class. First click makes the checkbox = true and button class=active, if i click on second checkbox, it makes previous checkbox = false and (this) = true, but it also makes the current button class=active without changing the previous button's class to default. 
I would really appreciate any help in this matter.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way to handle an *exclusive state* is to make **all** of the objects one state (ex. off)and *then* go back and change the state of the active one to it's unique state (ex. on). So use jQuery selector `:checkbox` to make your life easier and `this` to filter in the checkbox/button that was actually clicked.

Also, I changed the HTML somewhat. It's following the pattern when Bootstrap is properly done.

`.container`~~~▼

~~~~~~~~~~~`.row`~~~▼

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`.col-md-6`~~~~~~~`.col-md-6`

The children of a `row` must add up to x=12, (ex. `.col-lg-4, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-4`)

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flat-ui/2.3.0/css/flat-ui.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<main class='container'>
  <section class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <i class="flaticon-groceries"></i>
        <span>Grocery</span>
        <a>select</a>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <i class="flaticon-cooking"></i>
        <span>Cooking</span>
        <a>select</a>
      </label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <i class="flaticon-house-cleaning"></i>
        <span>Cleaning</span>
        <a>select</a>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySelfHandyman">
        <i class="flaticon-handyman-1"></i>
        <span>Handyman</span>
        <a>select</a>
      </label>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```